# I couldnt login with my mail and password to chat with jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I want to login chat site with Jmeter requests but I couldn't do it. I login the website but I can login without mail and password. I used header manager, cookie manager but again I couldnt do it again. Can you help me to this situation please. I can login but I can't login with mail and password.

The website is this: https://geveze.chatovod.com/

Please help

I used header manager, cookie manager but again I couldnt do it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the majority of cases you won't be able to just replay the recorded script without performing [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) of the dynamic parameters

The website you're referencing uses [CSRF protection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/csrf) so in addition to credentials you need to provide co called [CSRF Token](https://portswigger.net/web-security/csrf/bypassing-token-validation)

This is how recorded script looks like and this is what you need to correlate:

[image]

The value of `csrf` input needs to be extracted from the previous request, this is where the token is:

[image]

More information: [What is CSRF & How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Websites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-csrf-load-testing)

Comment: Thank you CSRF extraction worked for me. This documentation is very helpful. I extracted CSRF from previous response header and I used it.